# exception while get value from ehcache

Tags: java, ehcache

I am using Ehcache in my java application. i used this code to put object in cache using id as key.

```
ehCache.put(new Element(myObject.getId(), myObject));
```

Using the same id i tried to get the object from ehcache using the below code

```
myObject = (MyObject) ehCache.get(myObject.getId())
                .getValue();
```

but this code returns nullpointer exception. How to change above code to get stored object from cache?

Comment: show more code this is not sufficient.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but if you want to retrieve `myObject` how come that you already have a valid object on which you can call `getId()`. Probably `myObject` is null when you call `ehCache.get`

Comment: @ Matthias am having some value in object. using that id value as key , stored object value into cache.